# Is $P(X+2 = x+2)$ the same as $P(X=x)$?

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

I'm trying to derive $E[X+c]$ and show that this equal $E[X] + c$ (where $c$ is a constant), however my logic relies on the above being true. If anything has an alternative proof that would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent because $\{\omega | X(\omega)+2=x+2\}$ is equal to $\{\omega | X(\omega)=x\}$.

To see this, suppose  we have for a particular $\omega$ that  $X(\omega)+2=x+2$, we can subtract two from both sides. Conversely,we can add $2$ to both sides.

$P(X+2=x+2)$ is actually short hand for $P(\{\omega | X(\omega)+2=x+2\})$.

As for your quesiton of interest,

\begin{align}E[X+c]&=\int_{\omega} (X+c)(\omega)dP(\omega)\\&=\int_{\omega} (X(\omega)+c)dP(\omega)\\
&=\int_\omega X(\omega) dP(\omega) + c\int_\omega dP(\omega) \\
&=E[X]+c\end{align}

You might be using definition using special case such as the discrete case, you might want to modify the proof accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, that is most helpful! In your answer what does  represent? Is it the probability density function of X?

Comment: It's an outcome from the [sample space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space). you might be using the definiton of $E[X]=\int xf(x) \, dx$, you might like to modify the proof accordingly.